# Conversion of BigDecimal to double

Tags: java, math, floating-point, precision, bigdecimal

While converting BigDecimal to double, extra precisions are getting added. 
Could you please suggest this. 
For Ex:

```
BigDecimal deci= new BigDecimal(1.23456789123457E+17);
double value = deci.doubleValue();
System.out.println(value);
```

And value prints `- 1.23456789123456992E17`. How come the last digit 7 is converted to `6992`? Is there is any way I can get the same input which I am passing to BigDecimal after converting to double?

Comment: No, you can't. Because that's the precision limit of `double`s. The last 7 becomes 6992 due to rounding errors, because the `double` data type is less precise, and so it rounds your input to a representable number.

Comment: @GiulioFranco You beat me to it ;)

Comment: @MartijnR since you're here, I can't remember if Java mandates rounding to a specific value (e.g. the "closest" or "biggest smaller than the input" representable number)

Comment: @GiulioFranco http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

Answer (score 3):

There are useful methods [`Math.nextUp()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-) and [`Math.nextDown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextDown-double-) which can help you to investigate this issue:

```
BigDecimal deci= new BigDecimal(1.23456789123457E+17);
double value = deci.doubleValue();
System.out.println(value);
System.out.println(Math.nextDown(value));
System.out.println(Math.nextUp(value));
```

The output is:

```
1.23456789123456992E17
1.23456789123456976E17
1.23456789123457008E17
```

So as you can see, the double number `...456976` is immediately followed by `...456992`, which in turn is immediately followed by `...457008`. So `BigDecimal.doubleValue()` should select between two closest numbers `...456992` and `...457008`. No other double number exist between them.

Actually you don't even need the `BigDecimal` for this test:

```
double value = 1.23456789123457E+17;
System.out.println(value); // prints 1.23456789123456992E17
```